# Azure app can't connect to external API - Https to Http

Tags: api, azure, http, ssl, https

My Azure application needs to connect to an API that is deployed on a remote server. The Azure app uses `https`, while the API uses `http`. To avoid a mixed content issue, I changed my API address to https. But now I receive the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

So in summary, using http for my API gives me a Mixed Content error, and using https for my API gives me an SSL-related error.

Does anyone have experience providing an SSL certificate to an API thats already been deployed? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you open that URL in a new tab?

Comment: If i use http for the API, it gives me a string of particular data in a JSON string. If I use https for API, it gives me the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: What happens if you open the HTTPS URL in a new tab?

Comment: This Site can't provide a secure connection                                                                   'address' sent an invalid response                                                                                  Try running windows network diagnostics                                                     ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Read the error details.

Comment: Those are the only details I receive on the page

Comment: Click the Advanced button in Chrome to see more details.